# TemplateBinding in Binding Path

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, templatebinding

I have an `Custom Control` with dependency property `Header`. In `Generic.xaml` there is a style for that control. I want to set visibility of some part of the template so that it depends on `Header` property from the control.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CustomControl1}">
                <Grid MinWidth="400" Focusable="False">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" 
                               Style="{DynamicResource SomeStyle}" 
                               Margin="0,0,80,0"
                               Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                        <TextBlock.Visibility>



                            <Binding Path="{TemplateBinding Header}">

                            or alternatively

                            <Binding Path="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">



                                <Binding.Converter>
                                    <converters:ValueConverterGroup>
                                        <converters:StringNullOrEmptyToBooleanConverter />
                                        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter />
                                    </converters:ValueConverterGroup>
                                </Binding.Converter>
                            </Binding>
                        </TextBlock.Visibility>
                    </TextBlock>

                   ...
```

This line throws an exception:

```
<Binding Path="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
```

According to the exception message there can't be a Binding inside Path property of Binding (I already knew that) xD

How could this be done without double-binding? How to access property of Custom Control without using TemplateBinding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Path` property of a `Binding` is not a DependencyProperty, I doubt you may want it to be like this:

```
<TextBlock.Visibility>
   <Binding Path="Header" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
          <Binding.Converter>
              <converters:ValueConverterGroup>
                   <converters:StringNullOrEmptyToBooleanConverter />
                    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter />
              </converters:ValueConverterGroup>
          </Binding.Converter>
   </Binding>
</TextBlock.Visibility>
```